# SEO - anchor and b tag combination for keywords

Tags: seo

On some pages, I put keywords within anchor tags. What's better to use for Google search:

```
<a href="some_url">keyword</a>
```

or

```
<a href="some_url"><b>keyword</b></a>
```

or

```
<b><a href="some_url">keyword</a></b>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't make difference.

However, general usage of `<b>, <i>, <u>` tags is not advised. Use CSS to adjust text display properties.

Comment: I've heard that b and strong tags affect keywords. I'm using CSS to adjust text display properties but SEO is very important too.

Comment: Nobody seems to be pointing this out but, while usage of b/i/u is generally discouraged, usage of `em` and `strong` is not. Use either of those and use some CSS to adjust rendering if necessary.